# Retrieving common data on different forms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

Lets take an example of WinForms applcation and making invoice. On the Invoice form we retrieve a list of products, so the user will be ale to pick products for current invoice. Lets also consider that during this process user realizes that he needs to add a new product (or edit current) to ProductList before he can place it in invoice. So he opens a ProductForm where all the products are retreived (again).
It could also be in opposite order, that user first edits Products, and then without closing the Products Form, opens new Invoice. The principle is that data is two times loaded, and effectively its the same data.

What is the propper way to handle this scenario, so we can tell one form that data is already loaded, and to retrieve that data from memory? And when all the consumers (Forms) of the data are closed, then also the data should be released from memory? Or I am going in wrong direction, and there is a better way?

Thanks,
Goran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitelly go with data loaded "twice" or you will introduce much worse problems.

Sharing data means sharing ObjectContext. Even in WinForms application this is considered as bad approach. Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) (it is about NHibernate but the description is valid for EF as well).

The problem is that ObjectContext is unit of work. If share context between two windows you can easily get into situation where you modify data in first window (without saving them!) and you continue in second window where you push save button but it will save data from both windows! You can't selectively save data only from one window when you share the context.

Answer (score 1):

If the Controls that are using the data are all child controls of a shared Parent control, then you could just pass around the datacontext, so that they all shared the same datacontext.

However, the general use case with databases, which is what backs EF in most cases, is to read the data in each time that it is needed.

A solution to this if as you say you already have the item being used in one form is to just take a Refrence to that item into your new form.

So in the case Where you have an invoice which has a Product List and you want to add to the product list, you could pass the product list from the invoice to the opening product list.

There are some issues with this:

- If another user changes the datasource while one has opened it (a.k.a. Concurrency)
- Handling save don't save scenarios where they may have made a change in one area that they don't actually want added to the data.

However, unless it is a true performance issues, I would just load the data every time. You can simplify this a lot by using the repository pattern, so you can just call a single method to get a list of products or an invoice, or whatever part of data you need.